# How to create and write an XML with "Document" (XOM) content

Tags: java, xml, serialization

I'm trying to create a XML file using "XOM", a library for Java. I created the structure of my XML with XOM API, but now I need to create a file with this structure, to persist this data.

The file called "config.xml" is created with FileWriter, but without any line inside it.

**Here's my code:**

```
    // Creating the main element
    Element projetoMusica = new Element("projetoMusica");

    // Creating the childs of "projetoMusica".
    Element notas = new Element("notas");
    Element acordes = new Element("acordes");
    Element campos = new Element("campos");
    Element acordeNota = new Element("acordeNota");
    Element campoNota = new Element("campoNota");
    Element campoAcorde = new Element("campoAcorde");

    // Associating the structure
    projetoMusica.appendChild("\n");
    projetoMusica.appendChild(notas);
    projetoMusica.appendChild("\n");
    projetoMusica.appendChild(acordes);
    projetoMusica.appendChild("\n");
    projetoMusica.appendChild(campos);
    projetoMusica.appendChild("\n");
    projetoMusica.appendChild(acordeNota);
    projetoMusica.appendChild("\n");
    projetoMusica.appendChild(campoNota);
    projetoMusica.appendChild("\n");
    projetoMusica.appendChild(campoAcorde);

    // Creating a Document object (from "XOM" API).
    Document doc = new Document(projetoMusica);

    try {
        FileWriter xmlFILE = new FileWriter("C:\\config.xml");
        PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(xmlFILE);
        write.print(doc.toXML());

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Administracao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

What can I do to write properly inside this .xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to call `write.flush()` for the buffered content of the writer to be written to the file. This is due to usage of the `PrintWriter(Writer x)` constructor, which does not auto flush content by default. See the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.Writer%29) for more info.

Comment: Thanks!! I need use a write.close() in the end too, no?

Comment: Yes, ideally you would call close() when finished.